# Copy folder to current path open in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

I'm trying to create a batch file that copies one folder to the current path open in command prompt.

This is the code I have, but it doesn't work.

```
@echo off
xcopy /s c:\Users\Alexander\Documents\Other d:\%cd%
pause
```

Comment: If you `echo d:\%cd%` you will probably see `d:\d:\currentpath` as `%cd%` can include the drive so just `"%cd%"` (Use quotes in case it has spaces)

Answer (score 3):

Over complicating things...

Just use ".", which means current directory, i.e.:

```
xcopy /s c:\blah\blah .
```